# get size of std::array and span generically at compile time

Tags: c++, c++20, type-traits

I searched a fair amount of time in the standard library but just can't find the name of the template function calculating the element count of a `std::array` type or `std::span` type or c-array type. What I mean is something similar to `get_element_count` in the example code below.

I am not looking for a solution, `get_element_count` works fine. I just believed there exists a standard function already.

The function must take a type as a parameter like `std::tuple_size` for e.g. but needs to be more generic.

**So the Question is:** What is the name of that function in the standard library? I am happy with the answer from @user17732522 which is that I cannot find it because it does not exist.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <span>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename>
inline constexpr size_t get_element_count = 0;

template<typename T, size_t N>
inline constexpr size_t get_element_count<std::array<T, N>> = N;

template<typename T, size_t N>
inline constexpr size_t get_element_count<std::span<T, N>> = N;

template<typename T, size_t N>
inline constexpr size_t get_element_count<T[N]> = N;

int main ()
{
        std::array<char, 7> a = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6'};
        std::span b = a;
        std::span<char, 7> c = a;
        char d[7] = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6'};
        long e[7] = { 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L};

        std::cout << get_element_count<decltype(a)> << std::endl;
        std::cout << get_element_count<decltype(b)> << std::endl;
        std::cout << get_element_count<decltype(c)> << std::endl;
        std::cout << get_element_count<decltype(d)> << std::endl;
        std::cout << get_element_count<decltype(e)> << std::endl;
}
```

And because some asked for an example where such a compile time function is needed and not only used:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
struct  S {T t; size_t n = N;};

using A = std::array<int, 5>;
using B = std::span<int, 5>;

template <typename T>
using C = S<typename T::value_type, 2 * get_element_count<T>>;

using D_double = C<A>;
using E_double = C<B>;
```

Comment: I've read the question a couple of times but I can't still see the problem. An `array` has `constexpr` size so, that's not it? (edit: I voted to close for lack of detail)

Comment: @TedLyngmo The size member is consexpr but you need an instance to call it. In my example I could replace decltype(x) with x.size() of course, but it is just an example. I need the size from the type. I need that to write some sfinae conditions.

Comment: That should be `std::tuple_size_v`. However, they removed support for it for fixed-extent `std::span` (https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/838) and they didn't yet add support for raw arrays (https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/1240). I guess you'll have to roll your own for now as you did.

Comment: @PatrickFromberg I am just saying that this is the usual interface used by the standard library for this purpose. There is no other. It's support is just at the moment (in my opinion) incomplete. I am wondering why they decided to not use the tuple interface for `std::span` in the end. The LWG issue (https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3212) only says that the decision was made after "_Lengthy discussion about the intended design_"-

Comment: It's still not clear what the question is. The shown compiles fine, and produces a list of 7s. What does "I need the size from the type" mean?

Comment: _"I need the size from the type. I need that to write some sfinae conditions"_  - perhaps you do. It'd be best that you express what you really want to do. If SFINAE doesn't compile, it's not the worst that could happen.